# RStudio's .Rhistory file size in gigabytes?

Tags: r, rstudio

In RStudio there's an `Always save history` option in *Preferences*. Is there any danger of the .Rhistory file growing huge (gigabytes) if it saves every command I type and copy/paste?

Comment: How much the .Rhistory file is growing each day you are using `R`? (at average)

Comment: Not much. I just don't know if leaving the option on is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At my PC the total amount of .Rhistory files (~500 files) is ~ 3 Mb. And I'm using R for 2 years.

I do not think it is worth to delete history files to preserve disk space.